# Python Flask index.html template inheritance issue

Tags: pycharm, jinja2, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to use template inheritance so that my index.html page can use the base.html page. The issue is that my PyCharm client does not seem to recognize the extends tag (for example base.html is not bold).

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title%}
Thermos-welcome
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

I should expect something like  this
[image]

index.html file

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title%}
Thermos-welcome
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>Data Quality</h1>
                    <p>To understand and measure</p>
                </header>
            </article>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title> {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css">

    <script src="../static/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header-container">
        <header class="wrapper clearfix">
            <a href="{{url_for('index.html')}}"></a> <h1 class="title">ENTERPRISE DATA QUALITY</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('add') }}">Add user</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Data Marketplace</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Data Maestro</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="main wrapper clearfix">

            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}

            {% block sidebar %}
                <aside>
                    <h3>aside</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante. Etiam bibendum iaculis libero, eget molestie nisl pharetra in. In semper consequat est, eu porta velit mollis nec. Curabitur posuere enim eget turpis feugiat tempor. Etiam ullamcorper lorem dapibus velit suscipit ultrices.</p>
                </aside>
            {% endblock %}

        </div> <!-- #main -->
    </div> <!-- #main-container -->

    <div class="footer-container">
        <footer class="wrapper">
            <h3>footer</h3>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../static/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to report that PyCharm Community Edition does not support the template highlighting that you are expecting. You will need to upgrade to PyCharm Professional to use this feature.

This is noted both here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

and here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/defining-template-directories.html

Comment: Does ```base.html``` reside in the same directory as ```index.html```

Comment: Yes same directory

Comment: Could you provide more information, such as version and edition of PyCharm, and the actual content from both templates? I'm assuming Jinja2 templates, is that correct?

Comment: PyCharm 2018.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-183.4886.43, built on December 18, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b26 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

In my base.html file - i needed to change the following line

{{url_for('index.html')}}

to:

{{url_for('index')}}